# Votes received beyond the cap not showing up in sort-by-time reputation

Tags: support, bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Today I got three upvotes and an accept on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10324027/405017). Due to the cap, not all those affected my rep. No problem.

However, [my reputation view](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2012-04-25%2022:35:50Z) does not show 'blank score' lines for the votes that didn't affect my rep. For that one answer I see only a +7 and a +15.

**Edit**: I see that if I sort by "post" there is now a grouping that lets me see the votes that didn't change my rep. So this is only a problem when sorting by time.

Comment: If this is a change, I don't like it. I'm narcissistic and needy and I want to _see_ when people vote me up, even if it didn't help my score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sorting by time, adjacent rep changes tied to the same post appear grouped.

For example, you earned

```
+40  4 hours ago    upvote  Plot points and rectangles in Ruby
```

and

```
+7   1 hour ago upvote  Specifying allowed values for a method parameter
```

In the first case, it's obvious that this change is because of 4 upvotes.

In the second, all upvotes are registered. But since you hit the rep cap, you can't tell how many times your answer was upvoted.

However, if some other post of yours gets upvoted, it should show up.

Comment: This sounds good, but look at Jon Skeet's rep (from Siva's answer); there are adjacent entries for the same post with blanks in there. Unless you're talking about adjacent entries for the same action (upvote and acceptance in separate bins); that seems plausible.

Comment: I just upvoted your answer to *Convert a Nokogiri document to a Ruby Hash*, and it shows up when sorting by time. It gets, however, grouped with the previous upvote to that question.

Comment: OK, you've proved it. For the rep alone (which you may also choose to revoke, now that I've seen the effect ;) I feel I must accept this answer.

Comment: No need to revoke. That looks like a good answer. (I say *looks like* because of my limited to non-existent knowledge when it comes to Nokogiri or Ruby). What I'm still trying to find out is how you managed to gain `202` rep from upvotes in a single day...